# Openlayers: Loading image while layer is invisible

Tags: javascript, openlayers, cql, openlayers-7

I'm using Openlayers 7.

Is it possible to force the layer source (ImageWMS) to load a CQL filtered image, i.e. to buffer it, while the layer is not visible?

I would like to avoid the image from a previous filter to flash on the map, when the filter is changed while the layer is invisible, and the layer is then subsequently made visible after the filter change. The flash of the old image is obviously for the duration of the new filtered image downloading.

Event imageloadend only seems to fire after the layer has been made visible, so while the filter had been updated programmatically, the image wasn't requested from the server and refreshed since the layer wasn't visible at the time of the filter change.

Comment: Keep the layer visible property true so it will be refreshed, and control the visibility to the user by setting the layer opacity to 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, that's a good idea and it will work. So, I take it that refreshing the source is not possible while the layer isn't visible.

Comment: There is no API method.  Image sources have a non-API `getImage()` method https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source/Image.js#L176 which is called by the renderer based on the view state.

Answer (score 0):

As possible option you could remove extra layers and save only base layer (like osm).